# ogr2ogr keep geometry when converting to CSV?

Tags: shapefile, convert, csv, ogr2ogr

Using ogr2ogr, how to keep the geometry when converting to CSV?
( Nothing relevant here: http://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html )

```
$ ogr2ogr -f "CSV" MyLayer.csv MyLayer.geojson
```

Here is the begin of the result file:

```
$ head -n4 MyLayer.csv
OBJECTID,ID,VAR1,VAR_TXT,VAR2,VAR_TXT
677406,145477,0,AB94,51,rocks � distribute
267075,145400,0,AB94,47,road acces � distribute
101700,145434,0,AB94,47,road acces � distribute
```

I would like to keep the geometry (X,Y) on the two first columns for example:

```
$ head -n4 MyLayer.csv
X,Y,OBJECTID,ID,VAR1,VAR_TXT,VAR2,VAR_TXT
152.282,635.743,677406,145477,0,AB94,51,rocks � distribute
150.624,632.052,267075,145400,0,AB94,47,road acces � distribute
151.194,631.049,101700,145434,0,AB94,47,road acces � distribute
```

And I encountered an error if I translate the same data but as a shapefile (or a *.mif Mapinfo file) to CSV:

```
$ ogr2ogr -f "CSV" MyLayer2.csv MyLayer.shp
FAILED: Layer MyLayer already exists, and -append not specified.
        Consider using -append, or -overwrite.
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation of layer MyLayer (use -skipfailures to skip errors)
```

It seems it absolutely wants to keep using the previously named file (from the conversion from the GeoJSON file above).

---

Usage of ogr2ogr:

```
Usage: ogr2ogr [--help-general] [-skipfailures] [-append] [-update]
           [-select field_list] [-where restricted_where]
           [-progress] [-sql <sql statement>] [-dialect dialect]
           [-preserve_fid] [-fid FID]
           [-spat xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-geomfield field]
           [-a_srs srs_def] [-t_srs srs_def] [-s_srs srs_def]
           [-f format_name] [-overwrite] [[-dsco NAME=VALUE] ...]
           dst_datasource_name src_datasource_name
           [-lco NAME=VALUE] [-nln name] [-nlt type] [-dim 2|3|layer_dim] [layer [layer ...]]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the coordinates, see [Getting list of coordinates for points in layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8844/get-list-of-coordinates-for-points-in-a-layer) or [Reproject CSV file to different projecton using ogr2ogr](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91446/reproject-csv-file-to-different-projecton-using-ogr2ogr)

`-lco GEOMETRY=AS_XY` is what you need.

For the error part, just do as you are told:

```
 ogr2ogr -f "CSV" -overwrite MyLayer2.csv MyLayer.shp
```

This will destroy any previous content of the csv file, and add values from the shapefile to the CSV.

Answer (score 4):

Ok thanks, it's working now but as I have lines features, the `GEOMETRY=AS_XY` doesn't work, of course.
I need to set `-lco GEOMETRY=AS_WKT` to store the whole line :

```
$ ogr2ogr -f "CSV" MyLayer.csv MyLayer.geojson -lco GEOMETRY=AS_WKT
```

And if I set the `-overwrite` flag I still have some error if I run the same translation as before (but it's working if I make the conversion from an other data source, like a shapefile for example and with an other destination name):

```
$ ogr2ogr -f "CSV" -overwrite MyLayer.csv MyLayer.geojson -lco GEOMETRY=AS_WKT
ERROR 1: Attempt to create csv layer (file) against a non-directory datasource.
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation of layer OGRGeoJSON (use -skipfailures to skip errors)
```

Anyway, this is not really important as removing the file prior to the command is working fine.

**Tip fore more convenience:**
If you need to process the output file using a stream editor after that, I **highly** recommend to set `-lco SEPARATOR=` to something **other** than `COMMA` which is the **default** because comma is used as the field separators **AND** as the coordinates separator of your lines' points!