# Software to easily go CSV - map - CSV for editing

Tags: cartography, csv, software-recommendations

I am looking for a piece of software that will easily let me display lat long points from a CSV file on a map, then be able to select a group of points (via a box or drawing), delete the points and resave as a CSV.

- ArcGIS requires way too many steps to do this over and over again
- Power map in Excel shows the points but can't be edited
- Tableaux shows the points on a map, allows me to filter the bad points out but have not found a way to then resave the filtered data to a new CSV.

This should be simple.

Comment: For software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange

Comment: QGIS can do that, but I don't know if it is faster than ArcGIS.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS can do that, though probably similar to how ArcGIS does. I don't use ArcGIS, so I cannot tell if you will be satisfied.

If you need to "do this over and over again", you should consider using a simple script instead of a GUI.

`ogr2ogr` or maybe `postgis` would be possible.

Here is an ogr2ogr example how it could work:

```
ogr2ogr -f CSV outfile.csv -dialect sqlite -sql 'SELECT * FROM infile WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(MakePoint(CAST(x AS float),CAST(y AS float)), MakePolygon([...]))` infile.csv
```

Some Pointers:

- [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html)
- [ogr2ogr CSV Driver](http://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html)
- [Related Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/91448/87998)

Answer (score 0):

FME is really useful for this task (but it's commercial, not open source). It supports conversion of almost all spatial formats and allows advanced filtering.  https://www.safe.com/fme/fme-desktop/

Using FME to read or write Comma Separated Value (CSV) data:
https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/687/using-fme-to-read-or-write-comma-separated-value-c.html